# How to cut open a vertex into two vertices

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I want to cut a vertex into two. I would like to obtain a result similar to the picture:

[image]

[image]
(result obtained manually)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select a vertex, put your mouse cursor on the side where you want to have a new vertex and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, then in *Edge Select Mode*, select the edge and press <kbd>X</kbd> to delete:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! Just curious, what does Alt D do?

Comment: it duplicates the vertex but keep it on the same edge